# Strange\unexpected behavior with class_weight and LightGBM

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I have a LGBM model which does not use the 'class_weight' parameter.

When I run the model I currently achieve a score of 0.81659.

When I apply:  class_weight='balanced'
the score drops substantially to 0.78134.  A loss of 0.03525.

When I manually compute the weights and apply it with: class_weight={0: 0.61378, 2: 0.86751, 1: 4.58652}
the score drops to 0.78129.

I attribute the minor difference between my manual calculation and 'balanced'
to be rounding error, since I arbitrarily truncated the weights to 5 decimal places.

There are three labels distributed as follows:  Counter({0: 32259, 2: 22824, 1: 4317})

Let's pretend the labels were distributed as 33%, 33%, 34%.  I would expect applying class weights or
not applying them to have virtually the same impact.  There is no reason to expect using class weights in this case to have much, if any, impact.

But the actual data is quite imbalanced.

I would expect setting up the model to have knowledge of this imbalance would allow the model to make a more informed, i.e., better prediction, even if 'better' is only a slight improvement.

I certainly would not expect a 3.5% drop in model performance.

Am I not applying the weights correctly?

Main code block:

```
                model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(learning_rate=i,
                                           num_leaves=j,
                                           objective='multiclass',
                                           colsample_bytree=c,
                                           max_bin=512,
                                           n_estimators=n,
                                           class_weight={0: 0.61378, 2: 0.86751, 1: 4.58652},
                                           random_state=13,
                                           n_jobs=-1,
                                           )

                # define evaluation procedure
                cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=13)
                # evaluate model
                scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
                # summarize performance
                # print('Mean accuracy: %.3f' % np.mean(scores))
                print(f'For {i} learning_rate, {j} num_leaves, {c} colsample_bytree, {n} n_estimators:\n'
                      f'  The Mean accuracy is: {np.mean(scores):.5f}, The Standard Deviation is: {np.std(scores):.3f}')
                mean_accuracy.append(np.mean(scores))
```

Comment: As I can see, you're doing some sort of manual hyperparameter optimization, where each time you'll get a certain set of hyperparameters and for each scenario that you described, the values of the set is different. I am quite certain that if you'd try to use the same set each time, your weighted classes would be better than balanced. Also, it means that your HPO is not the best and could be much better for imbalanced HPO. Please correct if my assumptions are wrong, do more tryouts (maybe use Optuna for HPO) and, if problem still occurs, try to reproduce the code with some public dataset

Comment: @Rafa, I am doing a manual grid search.  Since I am using RepeatedStratifiedKFold with 10/3 I take the mean of each group of 30 trials.  So your take on my methodology is correct.  However, I do not understand when you say: I am quite certain that if you'd try to use the same set each time, your weighted classes would be better than balanced.  The same set??

Comment: The same set (of hyperparameters) - try to use the same set of hyperparameters for each set of weights and see if then the results are matching the theoretical assumptions